# ReadWriteWeb-like sidebar scrolling

Tags: sidebar

Does a Wordpress plugin exist that allows one to have a sidebar that scrolls unevenly with the main content section for posts / pages that are longer than the length of the sidebar?

I saw this on http://www.readwriteweb.com, which cunningly prevents 'white space' from ever appearing on the sidebar when the articles are longer than the total length of the sidebar. Very clever and would be nice to see if something exists for Wordpress like this.

Comment: I guess, there'll not be a plugin for this, you better make one.

Comment: I think this is overly specific interface detail to exist as plugin. There are scripts out there to achieve this and some themes probably include such effect, but as plugin is doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This is a **jQuery/parallax** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 0):

Its from [scrollspy in Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy).  Look at RWW javascript file for inspiration on how you might apply it to your sidebar div id.  As well as the bootstrap docs.

Kind of hard to make it into a plugin since you don't know what html classes or ids a give websites sidebar will be using.